# Converting string vector into custom object vector

Tags: c++, vector

So I have a string vector `values` but I want to convert this vector into a vector of type `Game`, which is my own custom class. How would I go about this?

I'm trying something like this:

```
void set_games(vector <string> values){ 
    vector <Game> tmp(values.begin(), values.end()); 
    games = tmp;
}
```

but it's not working. Any suggestions?

Current error message:

```
no matching function for call to ‘Game::Game(const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)’
./classes/game.h:12: note: candidates are: Game::Game()
./classes/game.h:9: note: Game::Game(const Game&)
```

**Update:**

Added `Game` constructor parameter. Everything working as expected.

Comment: [`std::transform()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)?

Comment: 'its not working' In what way is it not working? Good grief!

Comment: Hah sorry. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the error message says it all. You need a constructor for Game that takes a single string argument.

```
class Game
{
public:
    Game(const std::string& s) { ... }
    ...
```

Once you've done that you could improve the efficiency of your code by ditching the `tmp` variable

```
games.assign(values.begin(), values.end());
```

Alternatively if another constructor isn't sensible from a design point of view then `std::transform` as Oli suggested.

Comment: Just to make it clear, that constructor needs to contain all the logic to construct a sensible `Game` object corresponding to the string you pass. If you leave that constructor empty, you'll get a vector full of  empty, useless `Game`s.